# Possible to hash a value in microsoft access?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am working on a simple database using Microsoft Access 2013 with a MySQL backend via ODBC. I want to include some very basic form of user tracking, and I plan on doing this by prompting users for a username and password upon opening the database and comparing these to values in MySQL. Security is NOT a big issue -- I just want something that works and ideally doesn't rely on storing passwords in plaintext. Is there some easy way in Access to calculate the hash of a string so that I can avoid relying on plaintext storage of passwords?

Comment: See [this search result](https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+calculate+hash+value), which lists many pages with examples, some of which are already on Stack Overflow.  One of those results leads to [this page](http://www.frez.co.uk/vb6.aspx).

Comment: Definitely a duplicate, one of the answers in the linked thread worked perfectly (the one with code for calculating SHA1)